# C++ Why Sendmessage doesnt work?

Tags: c++, winapi, handle, sendmessage, hwnd

In C#, this SendMessage function raise up volume successfull:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

SendMessage(Handle, 0x319, (int)Handle, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
```

But in C++, this SendMessage function dont work, that is volume doesnt rise up:

```
// HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(...
SetWindowText(hwnd, "Hi"); // Worked
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_APPCOMMAND, (int)hwnd, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP); // Don't work
```

What do I wrong? Can you help me how to fix it? Thank you!

Full code:

```
#include <windows.h>
HHOOK _hhook;
HWND hwnd;
HINSTANCE _hInstance;

KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct;

LRESULT __stdcall HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            // lParam is the pointer to the struct containing the data needed, so cast and assign it to kdbStruct.
            kbdStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
            // a key (non-system) is pressed.
            if (kbdStruct.vkCode == VK_F1)
            {
                // F1 is pressed!
                SetWindowText(hwnd, "Hi");
                SendMessage(hwnd, WM_APPCOMMAND, (WPARAM)hwnd, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
                //MessageBox(NULL, "F1 is pressed!", "key pressed", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hhook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam );
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow );

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow ) 
{
    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject( WHITE_BRUSH );
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_HAND );
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("Philip");
    wc.lpszMenuName = 0;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    RegisterClass( &wc );
    hwnd = CreateWindow(
        TEXT("Philip"),
        TEXT("Hello World!"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        10, 10,
        500, 200,
        NULL, NULL,
        hInstance, NULL );

    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow );
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    _hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookCallback, NULL, 0);

    MSG msg;
    while( GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) )
    {
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(   HWND hwnd,
                            UINT message,
                            WPARAM wparam,
                            LPARAM lparam )
{

    switch( message )
    {

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage( 0 ) ;
        return 0;
        break;


    }
    return DefWindowProc( hwnd, message, wparam, lparam );
}
```

Comment: We need a better description of the problem than "it didn't work."

Comment: What exactly doesn't work

Comment: Was the window actually created or are you sending the message to `NULL`? We have no idea what's happening before you call `SendMessage` so it's hard to tell if the values you pass it are valid.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: I call it after `ShowWindow` and `UpdateWindow`

Comment: @TuyenTk Believe it or not, we already know from your code that you're calling it after `ShowWindow` and `UpdateWindow`. The point is that that isn't enough information.

Comment: Show us how you create the window. Chances are the call to `CreateWindow` is failing and you are passing `SendMessage` an invalid window handle.

Comment: You might want to familiarize yourself with the notion of a [Short Self Contained Correct/Compilable Example - SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). And post code that actually compiles. As it is now this is turning into an extended discussion on _how to ask a question_.

Comment: Compilable example, or it didn't happen

Comment: What's the return value of SendMessage?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on your WndProc, you'll see that SendMessage successfully delivered the message. The problem is not with SendMessage; please update the title accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `MAKELPARAM` macro to pass `APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP` to SendMessage `MAKELPARAM(0,APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP)`
Final version should look like

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_APPCOMMAND, (WPARAM)hwnd, MAKELPARAM(0,APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP));
```

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation I was able to get this working. The problem stems from passing an improperly formed `lParam` value. The command itself resides in the upper 16 bits of the value but you are not accounting for this. The following change should get you on your way:

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_APPCOMMAND, (WPARAM)hwnd, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP << 16);
```