# Getting text from a control in another application, using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, pointers, winapi, ipc

#### [ - Introduction - ]

I have software (*[Altair](http://www.flir.com.hk/cs/display/?id=42413)*) that interfaces with some measurement equipment. A limited set of functionalities of this software is exposed as an API, made available to me by the manufacturer in the form of its MATLAB implementation (with no extra documentation). Based on the provided sources, I know that all communications with this application use either [`Kernel32.dll`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files#KERNEL32.DLL) or [`user32.dll`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_USER) ([Windows API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) libraries), and more specifically the following methods:

- [RegisterWindowMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (`user32`)
- [PostMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (`user32`)
- [PeekMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (`user32`)
- [GlobalGetAtomName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (`Kernel32`)

One of the features I'm missing in the API is the ability to retrieve a certain textual setting that is buried somewhere in this software. Fortunately, the setting appears inside a `TextBox` (with non-selectable text) within its UI.

**My objective is to obtain, within MATLAB, a string that appears inside this separate, non-MATLAB window**.

---

#### [ - My attempts - ]

A quick internet search revealed<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873404/get-text-from-another-application),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352236/reading-from-a-text-field-in-another-applications-window)</sup> that this *is* in fact possible, through the Windows API, if the `HWND` (Handle to Window) can be obtained for the specific control (or "window") that holds the required `String`. A [`WM_GETTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is then sent to the control, and the string is theoretically returned.

The first step I took was to check that a `HWND` is even obtainable. This was done using the [Microsoft Spy++ utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460756.aspx) (which is optionally available with [VS2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs)). Below is the result:

[image: Finding the text field in Spy++]

The above hierarchy means that the 4<sup>th</sup> `child` of class `Static` of the 3<sup>rd</sup> `child` of the 1<sup>st</sup> `child` ..... of the window "Altair" is what I'm looking for.

In terms of the Windows API, these methods appeared useful for traversing the window hierarchy and obtaining the string:

- [`EnumChildWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

  > *Enumerates the child windows that belong to the specified parent window by passing the handle to each child window, in turn, to an application-defined callback function. **EnumChildWindows** continues until the last child window is enumerated or the callback function returns **FALSE**.*

  Unfortunately, however, this is unusable since "*The MATLAB Shared Library interface does not support library functions with function pointer inputs.*" ([from the docs of `loadlibrary`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html#zmw57dd0e432297)), which just so happens to be an obligatory input of `EnumChildWindows`.
- [`FindWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`FindWindowEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx):

  > *Retrieves a handle to the top-level window whose class name and window name match the specified strings. This function does not search child windows. This function does not perform a case-sensitive search.*
  >
  > *To search child windows, beginning with a specified child window, use the [**FindWindowEx**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx) function.*
- [`GetWindowText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

  > *Copies the text of the specified window's title bar (if it has one) into a buffer. If the specified window is a control, the text of the control is copied. However, **GetWindowText** cannot retrieve the text of a control in another application.*
- [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

  > *Sends the specified message to a window or windows. The **SendMessage** function calls the window procedure for the specified window and does not return until the window procedure has processed the message.*

So I set out to create a `c` header file that would be used with MATLAB's [`loadlibrary`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html), and I've ended up with the following (`graphic_hack.h`  ) :

```c
// Windows Data Types: 
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
typedef unsigned int UINT;
typedef UINT WPARAM;
typedef long LPARAM;
typedef long LRESULT;
typedef unsigned long HANDLE;
typedef unsigned long HWND;
typedef unsigned long HICON;
typedef unsigned long HINSTANCE;
typedef int BOOL;
typedef const char *LPCSTR;
typedef char *LPSTR;
typedef char TCHAR;
typedef LPCSTR LPCTSTR;
typedef LPSTR LPTSTR;
typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
typedef long LONG;
typedef unsigned long ULONG;

#define STDCALL  __stdcall
#define CALLBACK __stdcall

// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
HWND STDCALL FindWindowA(LPCTSTR,LPCTSTR);               
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
HWND STDCALL FindWindowExA(HWND,HWND,LPCTSTR,LPCTSTR);
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
int STDCALL GetWindowTextA(HWND,LPTSTR,int);             
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx     
LRESULT STDCALL SendMessageA(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);
```

The above is a *manual* alternative to the noteworthy method suggested [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/184038#answer_172074), which generates a header for all available API methods using the following:

```matlab
[nf,warn] = loadlibrary('user32.dll',...
 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\windows.h',...
'alias','user','includepath','C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\',...
'includepath','C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\',...
'addheader','WinUser','mfilename','user_header');
```

The MATLAB code that gets me the `HWND` of the control is given below:

```matlab
if (libisloaded('gh'))
    unloadlibrary('gh')
end
[~,~]=loadlibrary('user32.dll', 'graphic_hack.h','alias','gh');
javaaddpath(fullfile(pwd,'User32Util.jar'));
%Debug: libfunctionsview gh;
%       libfunctions('gh','-full');
%% Obtain the Altair field handle using various trickery:
hwndAltair = calllib('gh','FindWindowA','Altair',[]); %Find the Altair Window
hTmp(1) = calllib('gh','FindWindowExA',hwndAltair,0,'AfxControlBar70','Capture Manager');
hTmp(2) = calllib('gh','FindWindowExA',hTmp(1),0,'Afx:00400000:48:00000000:01100078:00000000',[]);
hTmp(3) = calllib('gh','FindWindowExA',hTmp(2),0,'SysTabControl32',[]);
hTmp(4) = calllib('gh','FindWindowExA',hTmp(3),0,[],'');
hTmp(5) = calllib('gh','FindWindowExA',hTmp(4),0,'Static',[]);
for k = 1:4
  hTmp(5) = calllib('gh','FindWindowExA',hTmp(4),hTmp(5),'Static',[]);
end
```

---

#### [ - The actual problem- ]

The final step, which I am struggling with, it dispatching the [`WM_GETTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that would get me the string. Specifically, the problem, the way I understand it, has to do with the definition of input parameters for [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#code-snippet-1):

```
LRESULT WINAPI SendMessage(
  _In_ HWND   hWnd,
  _In_ UINT   Msg,
  _In_ WPARAM wParam,
  _In_ LPARAM lParam
);
```

> **wParam** [in]
>
> Type: WPARAM
>
> Additional message-specific information.
>
> **lParam** [in]
>
> Type: LPARAM
>
> Additional message-specific information.

In the case of the [`WM_GETTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are:

> **wParam**
>
> The maximum number of characters to be copied, including the terminating null character.
>
> ANSI applications may have the string in the buffer reduced in size (to a minimum of half that of the wParam value) due to conversion from ANSI to Unicode.
>
> **lParam**
>
> A pointer to the buffer that is to receive the text.

This presents me with a catch: on the one hand I am supposed to pass an `LPARAMS`, which according to the `typedef` in the header file is a `long` (which means MATLAB expects a numeric input), but it needs to be a pointer to a "text buffer", which means I *should probably* pass in something like [`libpointer​('String')`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/libpointer.html).

As it happens, others ran into related problems in the past, and [it was suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16111783/3372061) to employ the so-called [`MAKELPARAM` macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) defined as:

```c
#define MAKELPARAM(l, h) ((LPARAM) MAKELONG(l, h))
```

... in order to create proper `LPARAMS` from another type of input. Unfortunately, I found no way this could help me.

This may be a misunderstanding on my part of how to properly use pointers in MATLAB<sup>[3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-arguments-to-shared-library-functions.html#bqgcbv0-2),[4](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/working-with-pointers.html#btfpq6r-1)</sup>, or a limitation of MATLAB which I ran into. Either way, **I am asking how can I proceed in calling `SendMessage` from MATLAB**?

Comment: Soooo... no **TL; DR**?;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak That would be the introduction :)

Comment: You sure made life harder than it needs to be. Most of your problems are solved when using the appropriate system-provided interface for this: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). If you absolutely need to follow your proposed strategy, at least do call [SendMessageTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952.aspx) to prevent deadlocks. But really, calling the ANSI API is just wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable - ---care to elaborate? ...as an answer perhaps?--- saw your edit.

Comment: Too much to explain. The link provides better explanations than I could come up with. If you want a live demo, check out the [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521.aspx), that has similar features to Spy++, except that it operates off the accessible tree of items (not native windows).

Comment: @IInspectable well I can't argue that this method may not be optimal, but then again, I was totally unfamiliar with the Windows API until several days ago. Also consider that MATLAB might not be able to access the specific functionality you have in mind (which could greatly simplify things)...

Comment: The UI Automation interfaces are exposed as COM ([Component Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694363.aspx)) interfaces. COM can be consumed by any language that can interface with C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MATLAB's [External Functions interface](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-external-functions.html) allows calling functions in various languages, among which is Java. As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2389283/3372061), a popular Java library to interface with the Windows API is [Java Native Access (*JNA*)](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna).

It is demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20596632/3372061) how JNA can be harnessed to send a `WM_GETTEXT` message. Adapted for the specific needs of this question and transformed into a `static` method, the required Java-JNA code is shown below:

```java
package hack.graphic.devil

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LRESULT;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class User32Util {
    interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
        User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
        int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;

        LRESULT SendMessageA(HWND editHwnd, int wmGettext, long l, byte[] lParamStr);
    }

    public static String getStringFromHexHWND(String args0) {
        User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
        HWND target = new HWND(new Pointer(Long.decode(args0)));
        byte[] lParamStr = new byte[512];
        user32.SendMessageA(target, User32.WM_GETTEXT, 512, lParamStr);
        return Native.toString(lParamStr);
    }
}
```

The above code imports classes found in [an older branch of JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/w32-platform-cleanup) (specifically, [its `/src/com/sun/jna/` folder](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/w32-platform-cleanup/src/com/sun/jna)). After [packaging as a `.jar`](https://infotomb.com/27s3x.zip), this can then be called from MATLAB using:

```matlab
javaaddpath(fullfile(pwd,'User32Util.jar'));
...
str = char(hack.graphic.devil.User32Util.getStringFromHexHWND(['0x' dec2hex(hTmp(5))]));
```

`str` will then contain the desired `String`. **Q.E.F.**

Comment: This seems like an epic amount of text for, "how do I call a Win32 API function from MATLAB"?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - "_Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler_". If I asked it like that, it would be an ["XY problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Rather, my problem was obtaining a string from another application - which is what I tried to convey. Everything else answers the classic "what have you tried?". I see value, in terms of how helpful this Q&A will be for future readers, in presenting my the trail of thought. Especially if/when other answers appear that would show a better way.

Comment: No, it would not be an XY question. Not to mention that this is the wrong way to get text from a window in another process.